# C# Event to Notify Subscribers Based on Their Requirement

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

I have a class Shape which changes its color and it is supposed to notify subscribers when change occurs.  However, subscribers want to be notified like:

- **Subscriber1** wants to get notified only if Shape color changes to
  `green`, `yellow` or `red`
- **Subscriber2** wants to get notified only if Shape color gets changed to `red`
- **Subscriber3** wants to get notified any time Shape color changes to **any** color

Here is my Shape class

```
public class Shape  
{  
    public event EventHandler ColorChanged;  

    void ChangeColor()  
    {  
        // set new color 

        OnColorChanged(...);  

    }  

    protected virtual void OnColorChanged(MyEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if(ColorChanged != null)  
        {  
           ColorChanged(this, e);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

And my subscribers

```
public class Subscriber1
{
    public Subscriber1(Shape shape)
    {
        shape.ColorChanged += new EventHandler(OnColorChanged);
    }

    void OnColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this subscriber wants to get notified only if color changes to green, yellow and red
    }
}

public class Subscriber2
{
    public Subscriber2(Shape shape)
    {
        shape.ColorChanged += new EventHandler(OnColorChanged);
    }

    void OnColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this subscriber wants to get notified only if color changes to red
    }
}

public class Subscriber3
{
    public Subscriber3(Shape shape)
    {
        shape.ColorChanged += new EventHandler(OnColorChanged);
    }

    void OnColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this subscriber wants to get notified every time shape color changes
    }
}
```

How do I let Shape to notify these subscribers of color change on their preferred condition (i.e. I want to be notified only if your color changes to red)?

Every example I see notifies all subscribers of all changes, I am trying to make it so that

- Subscriber can tell Shape of what change they want to be notified
- Shape then notifies these subscribers only for what they asked for

Comment: You realize that you're talking about 4 separate events, here, right?

Comment: Well, if the event args included the new color value, each could take action or not depending on that value.  Easier than the code you will have to decide which events to fire in the Shape thing

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Not sure why 4, I guess you think so because of 4 colors (green, yellow, red, any) but no, that is not what I want.  What if there is many more subscribers and many many more color options?  Plus, what if I want to also subscribe to say SizeChanges and have events fire only for certain size changes and have only some Subscribers interested in Size change?

Comment: Consider WinForms.  It has events for SizeChanged, BackGroundColor changed and many many more.  Does each control have to "register" for those it cares about?  No.  They get fired with some info in event args and the controls decide what to do, if anything

Comment: @pixel: My point is that you're not talking about a single `ColorChanged` event, you're talking about having to keep track of an event for each changed color.

Comment: Look at an API Iike FileSystemWatcher. It has events but there are also specific filters client code can use to only get the events that it wants to handle. Since you want each subscriber to have its own filters, you can't do this with builtin events. They cannot be parameterized on a per subscriber basis. You need to design an API that might look like `shape.SubscribeColorChanged(OnColorChanged, ColorFilters.Red | ColorFilters.Green | ColorFilters.Yellow)`

Comment: @Plutonix I understand your point but it is not good analogy with WinForms events.  Imagine if I have to fire these events for every change and subscribers then react only to the ones they want (i.e Subscriber2 reacts only or Red color).  But imagine the notifications are sent over a network (just for sake of clarifying).  I dont want to keep getting stream of updates but get only what I am interested in

Comment: @pixel That would just mean that the code in the event handler is firing some network notification.  It should be checking the condition before doing that.

Comment: @pixel: Per your last edit; it is not possible using the multi-cast delegate event mechanism without modification, because there is no way to identify unique targets inside an invocation list.

Comment: OK, I get it, so I'll remove that last update then.  Thank you Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to maintain a list of delegates for each of the different possible subscription choices:

```
private Dictionary<Color, EventHandler> colorChangedHandlers;

private EventHandler color_changed_to_red;
private EventHandler color_changed_to_yellow;
.
.
.
// then, add all of the delegates to the list
```

And subscribers would have to call

```
shapeInstance.SubscribeColorChanged(EventHandler handler, params Color[] desiredColors);
```

And then, you would have to implement it, something like this:

```
public void SubscribeColorChanged(EventHandler handler, params Color[] colors)
{
  foreach (Color c in colors)
  {
    colorChangedHandlers[c] += handler;
  }
}
```

Naturally, you would need the companion `Unsubscribe` method, as well:

```
public void UnsubscribeColorChanged(EventHandler handler, params Color[] desiredColors)
{
  foreach (Color c in desiredColors)
  {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Color, EventHandler> kvp in colorChangedHandlers)
    {
      if (kvp.Key == c) {
        EventHandler tmp = kvp.Value;
        tmp -= handler;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, you would have to change your `OnColorChanged` method

```
protected virtual void OnColorChanged(Color color)
{
  colorChangedEventHandlers[color]?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

And all of this is just for a `ColorChanged` event that could be handled with a `NewColor` property on a derived class of `EventArgs`!! Plus, it would have to more complex for custom colors, since this only deals with values in the `Colors` enumeration. **This might be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it to anyone without a clear and desparate need for it.**

Comment: Note that your unsubscribe won't work because Value is a readonly property.

Comment: @mikez: Thx, fixed. Stupid compiler.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thank you, this gave me a good idea and partialy solution how to deal with my problem.

Comment: @pixel: I hope it works out for you, but it looks to me like this is going to end up requiring a LOT of boilerplate code, if you have a large number of options on a large number of events.